# How to create permalinks for Wordpress-WP Symposium forum threads?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am using Wordpress v3.8.1 and WP Symposium plugin for creating forum. I am able to achieve pretty links(permalinks) for blog posts/pages but not able to get pretty links for forum threads.

Permalink for the blog which works is:

> http://discuss.discountbox.in/discountbox-finally-got-really-wanted-offers-website

And link for the forum for which I want permalink is:

http://discuss.discountbox.in/forum?cid=1&show=1

How can we do it?

Comment: according to [the docs of WP Symposium](http://www.wpsymposium.com/get-started/), it's sufficient to get the permalinks right in Settings -> Permalinks (on the WordPress admin dashboard), the plugin should follow. Are you using your forum plugin on the same WP installation where you already setup pretty links?

Comment: Yes this is what I thought but it looks like it is not sufficient to set permalinks for the forum threads. The wordpress permalinks settings just work for pages.

Comment: Arent there any wordpress experts on stackoverflow????

Comment: have you seen [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalinks-not-working-69) on Wordpress's Support Forums...?

Comment: Ya tried it but doesnt work can you suggest anything apart from that?

Comment: have you tried contacting the plugin creators..? I see you already posted your question on their forum (I guess it's you: [http://www.wpsymposium.com/discuss/forum-plugin/forum-permalinks-issue/](http://www.wpsymposium.com/discuss/forum-plugin/forum-permalinks-issue/)), they suggested it may be a conflict with another plugin (you may want to try disabling all) and that you log a ticket with them, have you done that...?

Comment: Ya tried that as well, doesnt work....

Comment: I also asked if you logged a ticket with them, did you? It's the only option that I believe works here as apparently it's too complex / localized...

Comment: Yes I raise the ticket which helped me resolved the issue. Thanks